# How do evaluate $x = (5^2 \bmod 6)^4 \bmod 15?$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

$x = (5^2 \bmod 6)^4 \bmod 15$.

I wanted to turn $(5^2 \bmod 6)^4 \bmod 15$ into a constant, but I just lost hope when I saw how humongous the expression was.

Comment: Humongous? Is $1$ humongous? Maybe to a creature of size $10^{-4}$.

Comment: if you had 625, you could do 625-6x10 and do the same thing?

Comment: @internetlearning, yes $6 = 0 \mod 6$ so $600 = 0 \mod 6$ so $625 = 25 \mod 6$.

Comment: @internetlearning you should start thinking about accepting answers you find helpful.

Answer (score 13):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
&& (5^2 \bmod 6)^4 \bmod 15 \\
&=& (25 \bmod 6)^4 \bmod 15 \\
&=& (19 \bmod 6)^4 \bmod 15 \\
&=& (13 \bmod 6)^4 \bmod 15 \\
&=& (7 \bmod 6)^4 \bmod 15 \\
&=& (1 \bmod 6)^4 \bmod 15 \\ 
&=& 1^4 \bmod 15 \\
&=& 1 \bmod 15 \\
&=& 1
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: oh you can substract the quotient by the divisor?

Comment: @internetlearning, yes because $0 = 6 \mod 6$ we have $x - 0 = x- 6 \mod 6$.

Comment: @internetlearning, by the way I would have actually done $5^2 = (-1)^2 \mod 6$ but I thought it's simpler this way when you are just learning about mod.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just directly compute $5^2 = 25$.

Now we have $(25 \bmod 6)^4 \bmod 15 = 1^4 \bmod 15 = 1 \bmod 15$